# flatness and derived completion

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, derived-categories, ac.commutative-algebra, derived-algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a local ring of maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Let $\hat{A}$ be its completion.

If $A$ is noetherian , then we know that $A\rightarrow\hat{A}$ is faithfully flat.

If $A$ is not noetherian, then we know that it's false. Is there any statement such as:

$A\rightarrow\tilde{A}=R^{0}lim(A/\mathfrak{m}^{n})$ is faithfully flat?